# Float data type data shows null in attribute table

Tags: qgis, sql-server, import, floating-point

When I tried to open table from MS SQL Server, float data type data shows null in the attribute table.
It only shows only one record.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can readmore in this topic: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/50865#issuecomment-1321868181